# persistent connection id state through out a browser session using signalR

Tags: signalr-hub

I'm trying to build a chat engine whereby users id are represented by their auto generated signalR connection id. On page refresh, the connection id changes when a new connection is instantiated. Is there a way to persist the state of the connection id of a user until the browser session is ended (i.e until he ends his session on client).

Any guide or documentation? It really would help.

Answer (score 4):

The most common way would be to maintain a static `List<CustomType>` in your hub where the CustomType has properties UserId and ConnectionId

Here is an implmentation you can follow too:
http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/mapping-asp-net-signalr-connections-to-real-application-users

I write my connectionIds to a sql database in the SignalR.OnConnected event and delete them in the SignalR.OnDisconnected event, you will get some orphaned connections records in your table which is no big deal just made sure you have a created_date column and ignore any connections that are so many hours or days old depending on your needs. Also there is no Session in SignalR, don't even try it, it is a known issue. To get your current user, modern out of the box Microsoft MVC membership providers work fine. But you can also easily use a cookie to get the current user's name/id.

Comment: I had thought of using a database to maintain persistence of connection id like a dictionary. the user here is extra code and tracking states like a vigilante. what triggers the ondisconnected method? is it on page refresh?

Comment: Page Refresh or closing the browser both trigger the Signalr OnDisconnected method

Comment: Did you get things figured out?

Comment: using the database is my only choice. i override onconnected, ondisconnected and onreconnect to update the user's connection state and keep track of it. using Collections to manage state is a bad choice.

Comment: Yes I told you in my answer that I use the database.